# codeigniter: how to access more than one variable of other functions in one class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

For example I have a class like this

```
public function data() {
     $a = 1;
     $b = 2;
     $c = 3;
}

public function codeigniter() {
     $a, $b, $b //how i can get the value??
}
```

How can I get the value of `$a`, `$b`, `$c` so that I can use it in `codeigniter()` function? I use codeigniter? Do I need to add a `return;`?

Comment: How do you call both methods?

Comment: You need to learn about variable scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @Rizier123 I do not understand, what you mean?

Comment: @BayuAnggaSatrio Where and how do you call both methods ? You need to return the values from `data()` and pass it as arguments to `codeigniter()`

Comment: @Rizier123 i call both methods in the controller

Comment: Declare the variable $a, $b, $c globally and use inside the function as 
$this->a, $this->b, $this->c

Comment: @Nadeshwaran where I have to declare a that variables? The functions in I put on the model

Comment: Try class example_model extends CI_Model { public $a; public $b; public $c; }

Comment: @Nadeshwaran for example $a is generated from the results of mathematical operations and into an array, do I also have to be declared globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a array and store the values in it and return the array.

```
public function data() {
    $data = array();
    $data['a']=1;
    $data['b']=2;
    $data['c']=3;
    return $data;
}
```

Then you can simply call the function and access the returned data.

```
    public function codeigniter() {
     $data_value = $this->data();

          echo $data_value['a'];
          echo $data_value['b'];
          echo $data_value['c'];
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume the two function are in both class and in a controller class of codeigniter

```
class Sample extends CI_Controller {
// declare variables
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $c;

    public function __construct() {
        // call codeigniter method
        $this->codeigniter();
    }

    public function data() {
        $this->a = 10;
        $this->b = 11;
        $this->c = 12;
    }

    public function codeigniter() {

        // call method data();

        $this->data();

        echo $this->a; // prints 10
        echo $this->b; // prints 11
        echo $this->c; // prints 12


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get more than one variable from a function you must place those variables in an array and return the array

```
public function data() {

$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

$data = array();
array_push($data, $a,$b,$c);
return $data;
}//data function ends


public function codeigniter() {
    $data = $this->data();
//now use $data
}
```